# How to create GridView using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

How to create Gridview in Jetpack compose without using recycler view or android.widget.gridview ?

Comment: Since  Compose version 1.0.0-alpha09 there is a standard component: LazyVerticalGrid

Answer (score 56, accepted):

With `1.x.y` the [**`LazyVerticalGrid`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#lazyverticalgrid) composable provides **experimental support** for displaying items in a grid.

```
val numbers = (0..20).toList()

LazyVerticalGrid(
    columns = GridCells.Fixed(4)
) {
    items(numbers.size) {
        Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            Text(text = "Number")
            Text(text = "  $it",)
        }
    }
}
```

The  `columns = GridCells.Fixed(4)` would mean that there are 4 columns 1/4 of the parent wide.

[image]

```
val numbers = (0..20).toList()

LazyVerticalGrid(
    columns = GridCells.Adaptive(minSize = 64.dp)
) {
    items(numbers) {
        Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            Text(text = "Number")
            Text(text = "  $it",)
        }
    }
}
```

`columns = GridCells.Adaptive(minSize = 64.dp)` would mean that there will be as many columns as possible and every column will be at least 64.dp and all the columns will have equal width.

[image]

Comment: it might be removed in the future as Google suggest to use LazyColumn and Row/LazyRow instead of LazyVerticalGrid. https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#LazyVerticalGrid(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.GridCells,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Horizontal,kotlin.Function1)

Comment: how to use it with paging?

Comment: @adam-noor grid layouts are still supported here: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/grid/package-summary

They deprecated the one in the old package though.

Comment: pass "columns" instead of "cells" to LazyVerticalGrid

Answer (score 23):

***UPD***: Compose version 1.0.0-alpha09 introduces standard component:

> LazyVerticalGrid

Yet another solution based on LazyColumnFor (Jetpack Compose version 1.0.0-alpha04)

```
@Composable
fun <T> LazyGridFor(
    items: List<T>,
    rowSize: Int = 1,
    itemContent: @Composable BoxScope.(T) -> Unit,
) {
    val rows = items.chunked(rowSize)
    LazyColumnFor(rows) { row ->
        Row(Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth()) {
            for ((index, item) in row.withIndex()) {
                Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(1f / (rowSize - index))) {
                    itemContent(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
    
@Preview("LazyGridFor: example")
@Composable()
fun LazyGridForPreview() {
    val data = (1..100).map(Integer::toString)
    LazyGridFor(data, 3) { item ->
        Text(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how can we use `LazyVerticalGrid` with paging data...

Comment: `LazyColumnFor` doesn't exist no more

Answer (score 9):

I have created a adaptative grid layout:

##### Preveiw

[image: Jetpack compose adaptative grid layout landscape|tablette]

[image: Jetpack compose adaptative grid layout]

##### Code

```kotlin
LazyColumn(modifier = modifier) {
            ...
            val numberOfItemsByRow = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp / 200 // you can replace 200 by the minimum size you want your cells to have.

            items(items = trendingGameList.chunked(numberOfItemsByRow)) { rowItems ->
                Row(
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(14.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                ) {
                    for (game in rowItems) {
                        GameCard(game = game, onClick = { }, modifier = Modifier.weight(1F))
                    }
                }
                Spacer(Modifier.height(14.dp))
            }
            ...
        }
```

The full code is [here](https://github.com/sitatec/GameRes/blob/bbb65307ab5daab79770cd7eeb47e9a38887adef/android/app/src/main/java/dev/berete/gameres/ui/screens/home/HomeScreen.kt#L80).

I decided to implement my own adaptative grid layout because the existing [LazyVerticalGrid](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#lazyverticalgrid) is experimental and can be removed in the future, and to use it you have to annotate the compostables that uses it with [`@ExperimentalFoundationApi`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/ExperimentalFoundationApi) recursively:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalFoundationApi 
@Composable
fun A {
    LazyVerticalGrid {
        ...
    }
}

@ExperimentalFoundationApi 
@Composable
fun B {
 A {..}
}

@ExperimentalFoundationApi 
@Composable
fun C {
 B {..}
}
...
```

**OR** use the `@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)` which require the `-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn` compiler argument.

Comment: how to use it with paging data?

Answer (score 8):

As @Pavel Marchenko mentioned, `LazyVerticalGrid` is added from version `1.0.0-alpha09`

Here is a quick example:

```
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        cells = GridCells.Adaptive(96.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
    ) {
        items(bookList) { book ->
            Image(book.cover, modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
        }
    }
```

Comment: how to use it with paging data?

Answer (score 6):

Update to @Pavel Marchenko answer as some of the compose function's names changed:
LazyColumn() instead of LazyColumnFor() and use of items() functions is needed:

```
@Composable
fun <T> LazyGridFor(
  items: List<T>,
  rowSize: Int = 1,
  itemContent: @Composable BoxScope.(T) -> Unit,
) {
  LazyColumn {
    items(items = items.chunked(rowSize)) { row ->
      Row(Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth()) {
        for ((index, item) in row.withIndex()) {
          Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(1f / (rowSize - index))) {
            itemContent(item)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will cause paging3 not to load

Comment: how to use it with paging data?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a custom gridview for using android jetpack compose until they will not support official recycleview for Gridlayout in Compose.

```
@Composable
fun <T> GridView(
cols: Int = 0,
list: List<T>,
child: @Composable() (dataModal: T) -> Unit
) {

val rows = (list.size / cols) + (if (list.size % cols > 0) 1 else 0)
VerticalScroller(modifier = 
Modifier.fillMaxHeight().fillMaxHeight().drawBackground(color = colorResource(
    id = R.color.color_bg_application
))) {
    Table(columns = cols) {
        for (r in 0 until rows) {
            tableRow {
                for (c in 0 until cols) {
                    //Cell
                    val i = (r * cols) + c
                    if (i < list.size) {
                        child(list[i])
                    } else {
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

USE

```
 GridView(cols = 4, list = model.list,child = { Item( it) })
```

Item declaration

```
@Composable
fun Item(t: T) {
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since LazyVerticalGrid can't be used in a LazyColumn, can't use it in a scrollable page. I created a library for custom LazyGrid implementation in compose. It's lazy so it performs really well. There are different item placement types for different scenarios and it's really easy to use:

```
LazyColumn {
    item {
        Text(text = "Title")
    }
    LazyGrid(
        rows = listOf(),
        elementPerRow = 4,
        itemPlacementType = ItemPlacementType.FixedSize(itemWidth = 80.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp)
    ) { item, modifier ->
        CustomGridItem(item, modifier, onClick = { /* if needed */ })
    }
}
```

There is also a collapsible version. Further information, documentation, source code and a demo can be found in: https://github.com/yusufarisoy/lazy-grid

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.yusufarisoy:lazy-grid:1.0.0'
}
```

It's also restartable and skippable for compose compiler to work with best performance. About Compose metrics: https://chris.banes.dev/composable-metrics/

Comment: Your LazyGrid can only be used inside LazyListScope. That's just loop to create item inside column, same answer as @Krzysiulele, not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

LazyVerticalGrid Consumes the scroll state thereby making it useless inside a LazyColum

Here an implementation using only rows and columns

```
sealed class GridCells {

abstract val columns: Int

data class Fixed(val count: Int) : GridCells() {
    override val columns: Int = count
}

object Adaptive : GridCells() {
    override val columns: Int = 1
}}


@Composable
fun VerticalGrid(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    gridCells: GridCells,
    totalItems: Int,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(0.dp),
    content: @Composable (Int) -> Unit,
) {
Column(modifier = modifier) {
    val columnCount = when (gridCells) {
        is GridCells.Fixed -> gridCells.columns
        is GridCells.Adaptive -> ceil(sqrt(totalItems.toDouble())).toInt()
    }

    val rowCount = ceil(totalItems.toDouble()/columnCount).toInt()

    for(i in 0 until rowCount){
        Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            for (j in 0 until columnCount) {
                val index = j + i * columnCount
                Box(
                    Modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                        .padding(contentPadding)
                ) {
                    if (index < totalItems) {
                        content(index)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: awesome it will solved my nested scrolling issue in lazyColum

Answer (score 0):

Made a couple of changes to @Madhav 's answer (using `compose v1.0.0-alpha01`):

```
@Composable
fun <T> GridView(
        cols: Int = 1,
        list: List<T>,
        rowModifier: Modifier = Modifier,
        colModifier: Modifier = Modifier,
        child: @Composable (dataModal: T) -> Unit
) {

    val rows = (list.size / cols) + (if (list.size % cols > 0) 1 else 0)
    
    ScrollableColumn(modifier = colModifier) {
        
        for (r in 0 until rows) {
            Row(modifier = rowModifier, horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround) {
                for (cell in 0 until cols) {
                    val i = (r * cols) + cell
                    if (i < list.size) { child(list[i]) } else { break }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Usage**:

```
GridView(cols = 2, list = listOf("1", "2", "3", "4",)) {
     Text(text = it)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a LazyVerticalGrid inside a LazyColumn so found this way. Let's check it.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalLayoutApi::class)
@Composable
fun CustomGridView(
    cols: Int,
    count: Int,
    builder: @Composable (Int) -> Unit
) {
    FlowRow(
        maxItemsInEachRow = cols,
    ) {
        repeat(count) {
            Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth((1.0 / cols).toFloat())) {
                builder(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
 CustomGridView (
        cols = 2,
        count = data.count(),
        ) {
        index ->
        DetailsPieChartItem(
            data = Pair(data.keys.elementAt(index),  data.values.elementAt(index)),
            color = colors[index]
        )
    }
```

Preview:

[image]