# lazy horizontal grid in Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin

lazy horizontal grid in Compose ?
I need something like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaKuV.jpg

Comment: Try this thread-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58596541/how-to-create-gridview-using-jetpack-compose

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.valueof.io/blog/lazy-grids-gridcells-fixed-adaptive-custom-compose

```kotlin
LazyHorizontalGrid(
  rows = GridCells.Fixed(3),
){

}
```