# Compose : How to add new row when no space is available

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a set of custom object. For each object I want to add a new Composable.

```
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    ) {
        mySet.forEach { something ->
            MyComposableStuff(
                ...
            )
        }
    }
```

It works well when there are 7 or 8 of them. When there is more, I would like to add a new row automatically so that it remains visible on the screen. How to do it in compose?

Comment: Please see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58596541/how-to-create-gridview-using-jetpack-compose

Comment: Use FlowRow from Accompanist or LazyGrid (if MyComposableStuff has fixed width).

Answer (score 0):

You should use LazyGrid for that.

```
LazyVerticalGrid(cells = GridCells.Adaptive(100.dp)){
        items(20) {
            MySampleComposable()
        }
    }
```

GridCells.Adaptive(100.dp) means that the grid will try to put as many items as possible in a row while considering the minimum width of 100 dp for each item.
if you want a fixed number of items in each row, you can use GridCells.Fixed().