# How to create GridLayout using JetpackCompose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-gridlayout

```
<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
  ...
</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
```

In the grid layout, each column will automatically adapt to the widest view.

[image]

In JetpackCompose, I can only use:

```
Column {
  Box{
    Text()
    Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = xxxxxx))
  }
  ...
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: You can see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58597015/7090806

Answer (score 4):

If you want a Lazy Grid, you can use the Lazy Grids as shown [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#lazy-grids):

```
@Composable
fun PhotoGrid(photos: List<Photo>) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Adaptive(minSize = 128.dp)
    ) {
        items(photos) { photo ->
            PhotoItem(photo)
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want it Lazy, you can use the sample [Grid.kt](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetsnack/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetsnack/ui/components/Grid.kt) designed by the Jetpack Compose team in one of their sample apps:

```
@Composable
fun PhotoGrid(photos: List<Photo>) {
    VerticalGrid(
        columns = 2
    ) {
        photos.forEach { photo ->
            PhotoItem(photo)
        }
    }
}
```