# How do I get a good form layout in Compose?

Tags: kotlin, layout, compose-multiplatform

Here is something that many applications end up adding: an options screen.

Sample program:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Switch
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.window.singleWindowApplication

fun main() = singleWindowApplication {
    MaterialTheme {
        val (showSwitch1, setShowSwitch1) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        val (showSwitch2, setShowSwitch2) = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
        val (showSwitch3, setShowSwitch3) = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
            @Composable
            fun booleanSettingsItem(text: String, value: Boolean, valueSetter: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
                Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                    Text(text)
                    Switch(value, valueSetter)
                }
            }

            booleanSettingsItem(
                "A switch",
                showSwitch1, setShowSwitch1
            )
            booleanSettingsItem(
                "Another switch",
                showSwitch2, setShowSwitch2
            )
            booleanSettingsItem(
                "A third switch with an even longer label",
                showSwitch3, setShowSwitch3
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

[image: screenshot showing the three switches all out of alignment]

But as you can see, the switches don't line up.

What's the proper way to get a two-column layout so that all the value fields align? (Over in Swing, you can lean heavily on `GroupLayout`, and forms become fairly simple, if verbose.)

I did try some of the "grid" layouts provided by Compose, but they really seem more tailored to situations where every cell is the same size..? If that makes any sense.

**Attempt 1:** @JakubMroziński 's answer suggests putting two columns inside the row. That does sound logical as far as how you would lay it out on paper, so here we go, new sample program:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Switch
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.window.singleWindowApplication

fun main() = singleWindowApplication {
    MaterialTheme {
        val (showSwitch1, setShowSwitch1) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        val (showSwitch2, setShowSwitch2) = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
        val (showSwitch3, setShowSwitch3) = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

        Row {
            Column {
                Text("A switch")
                Text("Another switch")
                Text("A third switch with an even longer label")
            }

            Column {
                Switch(showSwitch1, setShowSwitch1)
                Switch(showSwitch2, setShowSwitch2)
                Switch(showSwitch3, setShowSwitch3)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But now the result is:

[image: screenshot showing the labels scrunched up against the top and the switches being spaced out more on the right.]

This makes sense, because now there is no row to align the labels and the switches.

**Attempt 2:** The other similar question had an answer which suggested using `LazyVerticalGrid`. So here is a version using that.

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.GridCells
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyVerticalGrid
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Switch
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.window.singleWindowApplication

fun main() = singleWindowApplication {
    MaterialTheme {
        val (showSwitch1, setShowSwitch1) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        val (showSwitch2, setShowSwitch2) = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
        val (showSwitch3, setShowSwitch3) = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

        LazyVerticalGrid(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
            columns = GridCells.Fixed(2)
        ) {
            item { Text("A switch") }
            item { Switch(showSwitch1, setShowSwitch1) }
            item { Text("Another switch") }
            item { Switch(showSwitch2, setShowSwitch2) }
            item { Text("A third switch with an even longer label") }
            item { Switch(showSwitch3, setShowSwitch3) }
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

[image: screenshot showing the labels and switches aligned but with too much spacing around the switches]

It's nearly good enough, but I want the first column to take as much space as possible, and the second column to take only what's necessary. Is there a way? Or do I have to resort to custom layout?

Comment: Oh it turns out my question is a duplicate after all, just found this other one :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73456120/how-to-create-gridlayout-using-jetpackcompose   It doesn't have an answer though.

Answer (score 0):

For simple layouts in Compose it is enough to use only `Row` and `Column` functions.

If you want to create two columns, you simply create a `Row` and put two `Column`s inside, like that:

```
Row {
    Column { ... }
    Column { ... }
}
```

If you want your layout to take whole window size, you can put `Modifier.fillMaxSize()` as `Row`'s modifier. You can also adjust each column's width using `Modifier.fillMaxWidth(screenPercentage)`.

To align content in column you should use `horizontalAlignment` parameter of `Column` function. If you want it to be centered, just use `Alignment.CenterHorizontally`.

Comment: Tried this - result is the labels don't line up with the switches anymore